# android efficient way to upload image to server

Tags: java, php, android, upload, android-volley

I'm looking for a way to upload an image from android to php server, currently I'm encoding the image to base64 and send it, but it's too slow, is there is a better way

I'm using volley as network client.

Comment: Use a multipart request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604820/how-to-upload-image-to-server

Comment: Maybe a few metrics we could benchmark. What does "too slow" really mean?

Comment: yup, I'm gonna go with multipart request approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My 2 cents:

Few things can be improved depending on what you are targeting.

1. If you are worried about **the data usage**, then you can decrease the size of the image before uploading. Now a days for the newer phone models, the picture resolutions are very high. You can alter the size of the image on the device itself before uploading. Eg: [How to resize image (Bitmap) to a given size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471226/how-to-resize-image-bitmap-to-a-given-size) and [Decrease image size without losing its quality in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)
2. If you are worried about **blocking user when the images are uploading**:

   - Do the uploading part in the background, so that you don't block the user from doing anything.
   - Also as suggested in comments you can do a multi-part upload so that in case something goes wrong with the upload, you don't have to upload the whole thing again.
3. If you are **only worried about the time taken** to upload:

   - You either need a better network connectivity or lower the image size. If you know most of your users will be in lower connectivity areas, then it might be fine to decrease size.
   - You can use some library like [Facebook's Network Connection
     Quality Checker
     Class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class) to check
     the current network quality when trying to upload and maybe wait for
     a good quality network before uploading.
   - You can choose to only upload on wi-fi and use `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the change in its state.
     Eg:
     [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   - See if volley supports `gzip` compression. If it does make sure you are compressing the requests. This way you are zipping your request data which can be a substantial improvement in the size. [Android Volley: gzip response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144992/android-volley-gzip-response)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's really really helpful :)